# calling function in window addEventListener popstate, not working

Tags: html, addeventlistener, pushstate, popstate

The problem i am facing is  in the GetAjaxPageBack function whenever i try to write any function in it, like split, or any other function it do nothing and if i commented out the line
var url = url.split("?");  is start working fine, but why i need to split the url and want to get the query string and want to resend it using ajax to fetch the records.

```
<script language="javascript">

function GetAjaxPageBack(url) {

//this line is not working  
var url = url.split("/"); 

alert(url);


/*  $.post(url,

function(data){     
    if (data != "") 
    {               

    }
}); 
*/}


function GetAjaxPage(value)
{   
if(value=='n')
{
    val     = $('#abc').val()+1;
    $('#abc').val(val);
}else
{
    val     = $('#abc').val()-1;
    $('#abc').val(val);
}
history.pushState(null, null, "?abc="+$('#abc').val());  

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {           
    GetAjaxPageBack(location);          
});


}

</script>

</head>



<body><br />
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="GetAjaxPage('p')">Prev</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="GetAjaxPage('n')">Next</a>

<br /><br />

<input type="text" name="abc" id="abc" value="1" >
```

please help out, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location isn't a string but a Location object. Try using it's native functions or converting it to a string first.

```
location.toString().split('/')
```